# Getting Angular Dart and Paper elements together

Tags: dart, angular-dart, paper-elements

I'm trying to put paper elements in my angularDart app, so I have put in my `pubspec.yaml` the following dependencies:

```
dependencies:
    angular: ">=1.0.0 <2.0.0"
    paper_elements: ">=0.5.0 <0.6.0"
```

And then when I try to `pub upgrade` I get the following:

> Pub: Upgrade Dependencies: Incompatible version constraints on
>   html5lib:
>   - angular 1.0.0 depends on version >=0.10.0 =0.11.0 <0.13.0

I'd really like to use the 1.0.0 (at least) version of angular Dart, however I was wondering if there was a way to satisfy both libs' dependencies. (and how does someone get to know what the correct dependencies' versions are)

Note that I tried doing the same with Polymer and facing the same problem (with a different dependency), so a general way of working around this would help, instead of just giving version numbers.

Comment: You can/should create a bug report in the Angular.dart repo to update the dependency constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use dependency overrides.

```
dependency_overrides:
  html5lib: 0.12.0
```

There is no way to satisfy both when their constraints have no common set.
It's at your own risk when one of them doesn't work properly with the specified version.

Comment: So now I do this, and then get another dependency mismatch. I think it can go like that for ever, right? Now it's the `arg` package.

Comment: Also, apparently it has already been suggested to update html5lib version. https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/1281

Comment: I had this several times but could always solve it with at most 3 dependency_overrides. This is a common problem when combining packages that move forward pretty fast. This kind of problem is much less common with packages that became more stable.

Comment: Hm ok, I could get it with 4. Thanks for the tip! But how did you choose  0.12.0 for example?

Comment: Polymer needs 0.12.0. I always tried to avoid to force a package to use an older version than requested because it may miss features the package needs. Forcing a newer version than requested is normally less of a problem.

Comment: Ah I see, and for those wondering, at the time we wrote this `0.12.0` is the latest version of `html5lib` on there  https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/html5lib Thanks Günter!